# How to pass a value for input type="number" to JS in Razor View

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a view, here's a fragment of it:

```html
@foreach (var item in Model.Items.ToList())
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="productIdCheckbox" value="@item.sLabel">
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.sLabel)    
        </td>
        <td>    
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Text)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.OEMCode)
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="number" name="qty" id="qty" min="1" max="1000" step="1" value="@item.Quantity" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="submit" data-url='@Url.Action("AddToCart", "Cart", new { id = item.Id, qty = // I DON'T KNOW HOW TO PASS IT HERE // })' class="addProductToCartBtn btn btn-success" value="Add to cart" />
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

This code invoke AddToCart method in CartController:

```
$('.addProductToCartBtn').click(function (event) {
    var url = $(this).data('url');
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'GET',
        success: function (resultFrom_CartSummaryLine) {
            // some logic here..
        }
    });
});
```

But I can't pass to this method the value for qty input. How can I do it?

To be clear this is a method from CartController in which I want to pass a value for qty parameter:

```
public PartialViewResult AddToCart(CartModel cart, int id, int qty)
{
    GetItemListProcedure_Result item = _itemRepository.GetItemByItemId(id).FirstOrDefault();
    if (item != null)
    {
        cart.AddItem(item, qty);
    }
    return PartialView("_CartSummaryLine", cart);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have made the `name="qty"` number input using an HTML helper too. Something like this:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => modelItem.Quantity, new {type = "number"})
```

Then you should be able to retrieve the value just like any other input element.

Is that what you're asking for? Or do you specifically need to retrieve this value via JS?

Edited:

Within your JS method, you can retrieve all of your values. Also, make it a POST ajax call so that you don't have to get the URL within the `data-url`. You can just add the parameters within the ajax call. Also add a `[HttpPost]` attribute to above your controller action method.

```js
$('.addProductToCartBtn').click(function (event) {
        var url = $(this).data('url');
        var idVal = $('[name="productIdCheckbox"]').val();
        var qtyVal = $('#qty').val()
        var cart = {
            sLabel: $('#...'), //whatever your selector for this is
            Text: $('#...'),
            OEMcode: $('#...') 
        };
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'POST',
            data: {cart: cart, id: idVal, qty: qtyVal},
            success: function (resultFrom_CartSummaryLine) {
                // some logic here..
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I didn't mention that this input has up and down arrows, so user can adjust the qty that he want to add to cart. So I need to pass a value that the user made, not initial quanity from model

Comment: Ok I see, it's not a part of the model like the other elements. You can just retrieve it via JS as shown above.

Comment: Thanks, I used your approach and it works for me. Just didn't understand why should I make a POST call. So, I left a GET call

Comment: It will likely work fine as a GET call, but a POST is more appropriate for this situation. Whenever you are sending data back to the server, as in saving some data, you should POST. GET will transfer data via the URL query string which can get really messy when you're dealing with complex objects, as you did in your situation.